# How to keep a tkinter window open when you stop the running script?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to know if any of you knew how to keep a tkinter window open when you stop the running script.   The idea is that there is data coming in, but to rerun the whole programme i need to stop the display script and i want that the display window stay open during the changes.
Here is the display code all the 0 are in datta
Thank you!!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
```

```
class GroupFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="gray94", borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):

        self.label = Label(self, text="Family :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.label = Label(self, text="Sub family :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.label = Label(self, text="Captor :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.label = Label(self, text="Nb of Insp lot :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.label = Label(self, text="Nb of equipement :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.label = Label(self, text="Equipement :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.text = Text(self, width=103, height=2, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 0)
        self.text.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(10, 5), sticky='w')

        self.text = ScrolledText(self, width=103, height=2, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT,0)
        self.text.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=(5), sticky='w')

        self.text = Text(self, width=103, height=2, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 0)
        self.text.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=(5), sticky='w')

        self.text = Text(self, width=103, height=1, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT,0)
        self.text.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=(5), sticky='w')

        self.text = Text(self, width=103, height=1, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 0)
        self.text.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=(5, 10), sticky='w')

        self.text = ScrolledText(self, width=103, height=8, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT,0)
        self.text.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=(5, 10))


class ImgFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='gray94', borderwidth=0, relief=GROOVE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        try:
            self.Imgfile = "Logo_Tiger_tout_blanc.png"
            self.img = PhotoImage(file=self.Imgfile)
            self.img_2 = self.img.subsample(3, 3)
            self.Image = Label(image=self.img_2, bg='gray94')
            self.Image.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='n')
        except:
            self.label = Label(self, text="title \n title title title", bg="gray94", font=("Calibri", 14))
            self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e', padx=5)


class CalibrationFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="gray94", borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.label = Label(self, text="Freq adjustment :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.label = Label(self, text="Avoided calibration :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.text = Text(self, width=23, height=1, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 0)
        self.text.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(27, 28))

        self.text = Text(self, width=23, height=1, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 0)
        self.text.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=(28))


class StatFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="gray94", borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.label = Label(self, text="Accepted :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e', pady=(10, 0))

        self.label = Label(self, text="Rejected :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.label = Label(self, text="Reject rate :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='e')

        self.label = Label(self, text="Pvalue :", bg="gray94")
        self.label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='e', pady=(0, 10))

        self.text = Text(self, width=25, height=1, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 0)
        self.text.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(19, 5))

        self.text = Text(self, width=25, height=1, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 0)
        self.text.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=(5))

        self.text = Text(self, width=25, height=1, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 0)
        self.text.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=(5))

        self.text = Text(self, width=25, height=1, font=("Calibri", 11), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 0)
        self.text.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=(5, 18))


class ButtonFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="gray94")
        self.parent = parent
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.Border1 = LabelFrame(self, bd=2, bg="DodgerBlue3", relief=FLAT)
        self.Border1.grid(row=1, pady=(5, 10), padx=(20, 20))
        self.Border2 = LabelFrame(self, bd=2, bg="DodgerBlue3", relief=FLAT)
        self.Border2.grid(row=2, pady=(10, 5))
        self.button1 = Button(self.Border1, text='Save in \n Database', command=self.parent.destroy, relief='flat',
                              bg='gray90', border=0,
                              highlightcolor='blue', activebackground='SlateGray1')
        self.button1.grid()
        self.button2 = Button(self.Border2, text='Close', command=self.parent.destroy, relief='flat', bg='gray90',
                              border=0,
                              highlightcolor='blue', activebackground='SlateGray1')
        self.button2.grid()


class MainW(Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.mainWidgets()
        self.title("title")

        self['bg'] = 'gray94'

    def mainWidgets(self):
        self.label = Label(self, text="Sub-group :", bg='gray94')
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w', padx=7)

        self.window = GroupFrame(self)
        self.window.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=5)

        self.window = ImgFrame(self)
        self.window.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.label = Label(self, text="Calibration :", bg='gray94')
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='w')

        self.window = CalibrationFrame(self)
        self.window.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='n')

        self.label = Label(self, text="Statistics :", bg='gray94')
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='w')

        self.window = StatFrame(self)
        self.window.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky='n')

        self.window = ButtonFrame(self)
        self.window.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(2), rowspan=3)

        self.label = Label(self, text="Response :", bg='gray94')
        self.label.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='w')

        self.text = Text(self, width=74, height=3, font=("Calibri", 15), wrap=WORD)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, 000)
        self.text.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=5, pady=(0, 5), padx=(0, 5))
```

```
focus = 0


def focus_in(event):
    global focus
    focus += 1


def focus_out(event):
    global focus
    focus -= 1
    if focus == 0:
        app.destroy()



app = MainW(NONE)
app.focus_force()
app.bind("<FocusOut>", focus_out)
app.bind("<FocusIn>", focus_in)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: In here: `self.button1 = Button(..., text='Save in \n Database', command=self.parent.destroy, ...)`, why do you destroy the parent?

Comment: It's just a not finished feature ;)

Comment: Well to be honest you can destroy the parent and bring it back as well. And all this without re-running the script. Parent can be destroyed and the program can still be executed.